# How to delete the borders and add the name in the bar itself

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I would like to delete the lines which are actually shown in the picture and also put the number (their values) in each graph, I mean the value which belong to each one. How can I do it? 
The values are from a data set taken from Kaggle.

[image]

Comment: Could you please add some of your existing and relevant code to your question so that it is easier to figure out the problem?

Comment: Please copy-paste the code as text, not as image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some code to help you get the requested layout.
The states and the numbers are from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2019_Amazon_rainforest_wildfires#2019_Brazil_dry_season_fires).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

states = ['Acre', 'Alagoas', 'Amazonas', 'Amapá', 'Bahia', 'Ceará', 'Federal District',
          'Espírito Santo', 'Goiás', 'Maranhão', 'Minas Gerais', 'Mato Grosso do Sul',
          'Mato Grosso', 'Pará', 'Paraíba', 'Pernambuco', 'Piauí', 'Paraná', 'Rio de Janeiro',
          'Rio Grande do Norte', 'Rondônia', 'Roraima', 'Rio Grande do Sul', 'Santa Catarina',
          'Sergipe', 'São Paulo', 'Tocantins']
fires = [2918, 73, 7625, 24, 2383, 327, 68, 229, 1786, 5596, 2919, 451, 15476, 10747, 81, 132,
         2818, 181, 396, 68, 6441, 4608, 2029, 1107, 62, 1616, 6436]
fires, states = zip(*sorted(zip(fires, states))) #sort both arrays on number of fires
fires = fires[-15:]   # limit to the 15 highest numbers
states = states[-15:]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 6))
ax.barh(states, fires, color="#08519c")
plt.box(False)  # remove the complete box around the plot
plt.xticks([])  # remove all the ticks on the x-axis
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('none') # removes the tick marks on the y-axis but leaves the text
for i, v in enumerate(fires):
    ax.text(v + 180, i, f'{v:,}'.replace(',', '.'), color='#08519c', fontweight='normal', ha='left', va='center')
plt.subplots_adjust(left=0.22)  # more space to read the names
plt.title('Wildfires Brazil 2019', fontsize=20, y=0.98) # title larger and a bit lower
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

PS: about

```
for i, v in enumerate(fires):
    ax.text(v + 180, i, f'{v:,}'.replace(',', '.'), color='#08519c', fontweight='normal', ha='left', va='center')
```

This has a `v` going through each element of fires, one by one. `i` is the index for which `fires[i] == b`. `ax.text(x, y, 'some text')` puts a text on a certain position, where they are measured with the same distances as those marked on the axes (that's why default the axes are shown). When the axes are just text instead of numbers, they are numbered internally 0, 1, 2, 3, ... . So, `x=v + 180` is the x-position where number-of-fires v+180 would be. And `y=i` means just the position of label number `i`.

Comment: Thank you, could you explain me how the cycle for works?